# Choosing a DHCP pool from which to assign an IP address

Tags: cisco, router, dhcp

I have Router, and there are three DHCP pools: `10.0.1.0/24`, `10.0.2.0/24`, and `10.0.3.0 /24`. Three LANs are connected to this router. If a host on the first LAN sends a DHCP Request, how does the router decide from which DHCP pool to assign the IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router will use the pool which is in the network assigned to the interface. Each router interface has an assigned IP address and mask. The pool which has addresses within the network (mask the interface address to get the network) is used.